# Subscript character 'g' and '/' in C#?

Tags: c#

How do I insert subscript 'g' and subscript '/' as a string in C#? I cannot see any alt-code that could express this.

Subscript is small like this: <sub>g</sub> and <sub>/</sub>

I have this

```
string iWantASubscriptG = "GIVE ME A SUBSCRIPT HERE <G>";
```

When I try to paste existing subscript characters into Visual Studio, it just changes them to regular full size characters, so I don't know how to enter these in a string literal.

Hopefully that makes it clearer... and I've tried finding the actual subscript symbol and copying it but it just results in a normal 'g'. Same goes for a division slash i.e. /

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214264/discussion-on-question-by-bobsyauncle-subscript-character-g-and-in-c).

Answer (score 0):

In all versions of Windows there is a character map program, find it by selecting the Windows icon and typing in `Character Map`. By the time you type in `char` it should show in the list of possible programs. Run it.

Then do these steps

[image]

1. Find the font being used/displayed in your application.
2. Scroll to the needed character which represents the super/sub scripted character. It might be a ways down the list...
3. Hover over the character to see what it is in the bubble text or select the character to get an exploded version of it.
4. Hit the select button to put it into the edit box.
5. Select `Copy` to put it in the clipboard.

Then paste it or use the hexadecimal value (*as shown in the bottom toolbar*) to display it in C#.

Comment: Unfortunately the answer to the question as posed is that it can't be done. There's no character that is both subscript and `g` at the same time. According to the tables found here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts - you can see that some subscript characters exist, such as ₐ, but the g cell is left empty. Yes, your answer shows how to get a smaller g, but it is not subscript, but again, that isn't possible to do anyway so the answer is simply "What you ask can't be done". The characters simply doesn't exist.

Comment: you'd think unicode would just add them in since it's used widely in the maths community but... oh well...

Comment: See [Is there a perfect maths font](http://chalkdustmagazine.com/blog/is-there-a-perfect-maths-font/)